# Read json data entries as objects in python file

Tags: python, json, fizzbuzz

I want to solve fizzbuzz problem using SOLID principles in python 
I wrote this code:

```
class tester(object):
    def check(self, number, string):
        return ", ".join(self.check_numbers(number, string))

    def check_numbers(self, number, string):
        number_list = []
        for n in range (1, 101):
            if n%number==0:
                number_list.append(string)
            else:
                number_list.append(str(n))
        return number_list
```

It works well. When I run the code I create an object by: `em = tester()` and then call the check function like: `em.check(3, "Fizz")`

They say: rules should be objects so I can add/register them to the rules executor dynamically, or via dependency injection
I thought of JSON file to store all the rules in and read them as objects in a .py file, but I got stuck.

Is there any help?

Comment: why do you use a class? there are just member functions but not data...

Comment: I instantiate data in running phase.

Comment: like this: 
    em=tester()
    em.checker(3, "Fizz")

Comment: do you recommend any other solution that use SOLID principles?

Comment: a class makes sense if you define a new datatype with its methods. you don't do that here, your datatype are plain `int`egers. so yes: i suggest you do not write a class for that. by the way: what does that all have to do with `json`?

Comment: They asked me to code rules as objects exclusively. for this reason I made a class.
and asked the rules should be addable to rules executor, so I thought of json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have a solution and here it is:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def is_divisible(number, modulo):
   return number % modulo == 0

FizzBuzz = namedtuple('FizzBuzz', 'number, name')

fizz_buzz_words = [
    FizzBuzz( 3, 'Fizz'),
    FizzBuzz( 4, 'Buzz'),
    FizzBuzz( 7, 'Bang'),
    FizzBuzz(11, 'Boom'),
 ]

def to_fizz_buzz_string(n):
    fizz_buzzes = [fb.name for fb in fizz_buzz_words if is_divisible(n, 
    fb.number)]

    return ''.join(fizz_buzzes) if fizz_buzzes else str(n)

for a in range(124, 134):
    print to_fizz_buzz_string(a)

print ', '.join(to_fizz_buzz_string(n) for n in range(923, 935))
```